# How to get bash script to check for consecutive capital letters

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have a folder with a bunch of JPEGs and I want to check if their filenames meet my filename criteria:  (1) no spaces, (2) no underscores, (3) no consecutive capital letters, (4) and each filename should end in "-original.jpg". I output any bad filenames, and then prompt the user to proceed or not. My script below works great for conditions (1), (2), and (4), but I want to add condition (3) as another elseif.

```
i=0  # Initialize issue counter

# Detect and indicate any filename issues
for file in *.jpg; do
    if [[ $file = *" "* ]] | [[ $file = *"_"* ]]
        then
        echo "Filename issue: " $file
        i=$((i+1))
    elif [[ $file != *"-original.jpg" ]] 
        then
        echo "Filename issue: " $file
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
done

# If condition satisfied, provide indication of no filename issues
if [[ $i == 0 ]]
then
  echo "No filename issues"
fi
echo

# Prompt user if they want to continue with image processing
read -p "Proceed with image processing? (enter 'y' or 'n') " yn
case $yn in
  [Yy]* ) 
    echo 
    echo "PROCEED"
    echo
    break;;
  [Nn]* ) echo; exit;;
   * ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";;
esac
```

I was able to cobble this together for condition (3) and it detects consecutive capitals, but I can't figure out how to make it output the larger string ($name) it's parsing and/or pass a variable back to the larger shell script. What's the best way to do this?

```
echo "$name" | 
awk '{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i ~ /[A-Z]/ && $(i+1) ~ /[A-Z]/) {
         echo "capitalization problem"
      }
      echo "no capitalization problem"
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regexp pattern matching provided by bash using the `=~` inside `[[ ]]`

```
if [[ $name =~ [[:upper:]]{2} ]]; then
  printf 'Capitalize problem!\n'
else
  prinf 'No capitalize problem.\n'
fi
```

As mentioned by @shawn, updated to `[[:upper:]]{2}`

Comment: For *"no consecutive capital letters"*, wouldn't that be `[[:upper:]]+`? (or `[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]` using BRE)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you for that wonderful comment. Updated the answer.

Comment: `[[:upper:]]+` will match any single capital letter. `[[:upper:]]{2}` for two consecutive capitals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `grep` pipeline to check for conestive uppercase characters, something like

```sh
pax:/> if echo aBbd | grep '[A-Z][A-Z]' >/dev/null ; then echo bad ; fi
pax:/> if echo aBBd | grep '[A-Z][A-Z]' >/dev/null ; then echo bad ; fi
bad
```

Just replace the fixed string being echoed with your actual file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*` glob:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch {a,A}{b,B}{c,C}.jpg
$ ls
abc.jpg  abC.jpg  aBc.jpg  aBC.jpg  Abc.jpg  AbC.jpg  ABc.jpg  ABC.jpg
$ ls *[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*
aBC.jpg  ABc.jpg  ABC.jpg
```

This will be much faster than looping through the entire list of files and checking the pattern of them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine some of those tests together:

```sh
for file in *.jpg; do
    if [[ $file =~ [[:space:]_]|[[:upper:]]{2} ]] || [[ $file != *-original.jpg ]]
        then
        echo "Filename issue: $file"
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
done
```

First use a regular expression to look for space, underscore, or two consecutive upper case letters, and then a wildcard pattern see if the file doesn't end in `-original.jpg`. If either test succeeds, it's an invalid filename. If both fail, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

To simply and efficiently test for (1) no spaces, (2) no underscores, (3) no consecutive capital letters, (4) and each filename should end in "-original.jpg" using any POSIX awk in any shell:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    if ( ARGV[1] == "*.jpg" ) {
        exit
    }
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        fname = ARGV[i]
        if ( (fname ~ /[[:space:]_]|[[:upper:]]{2}/) || (fname !~ /-original\.jpg$/) ) {
            gotBad = 1
            print "Filename issue:", fname | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
}
END {
    if ( ! gotBad ) {
        print "No filename issues" | "cat>&2"
    }
    exit gotBad
}
' *.jpg
```